# Stopping time and martingale of $ \min \left\{ n \geq 1 : X_n = Y_n \right\}$

Tags: martingales, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1},\mathbb{P})\;$ be a given filtrated probability space, and $X = (X_n)_{n≥1}$ , $Y = (Y_n)_{n≥1}\;$  be two
$(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1}$-martingales. 
Set
$$ \tau := \min \left\{  n \geq 1 : X_n = Y_n \right\} $$
 How we can show that $\tau\;$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1}$-stopping time ?

And let $$ Z_n:=(X_n-Y_n)\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ \tau \geq n \right\}}$$
How can we show that $ (Z_n)_{n≥1}$ is an $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n≥1}$-martingale ?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? What do you need to show in order to verfiy that $\tau$ is a stopping time?

Comment: I've already tried it, but I didn't get the result

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? Please add your thoughts/calculations/... on the problem to the body of your question.